# RedBeanPHP & User Input Data Sanitation

Tags: php, redbean

I've been testing [RedBeanPHP](http://www.redbeanphp.com/).

I'm wondering about sanitizing user input. Do I need to manually sanitize data or will RedBeanPHP take care of that?

Comment: Their mailing list is here http://groups.google.com/group/redbeanorm?pli=1

Comment: Thanks Treffynnon. I've posted my question over there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RedBeanPHP uses PDO bindings to protect against SQL injection so you don't need to escape manually. However input validation (checking whether the input is valid) should be done using your own models or validation routines.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. RedBeanPHP is great to use. It really simplifies things for a small php site. :)

Comment: Don't forget to escape HTML and JavaScript, RedBeanPHP doesn't handle XSS or HTMLi, but does a great job at taking care of SQLi